# How to set rollback to false for just one method in the JUnit test class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit

I have a very big class which contains a lot of methods.
I would like to ignore the rollback just for one method. i am aware that we can set this in the class level like here below but i don't want for all methods:
**Is there a way to do it?**

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class TestPersistence {

   @Test
   void testBasicLogCreation(){

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This annotation should do it.

```
@Rollback(false)
```

> @Rollback is a test annotation that is used to indicate whether a
>   test-managed transaction should be rolled back after the test method
>   has completed.

More information in [javaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Rollback.html).

Comment: Tanks for your reply, i added this annotation to it , test pass but nothing is added into the data bank.

Comment: Do you want to say that it is still working incorrect and you expected something else?